# Dependency Injection and `new` in __construct

Tags: php

I'm new to OOP and I don't quite understand about dependency injection.

Say I have a abstract class `Responder`, and have it extended into `SuccessResponder` and `ErrorResponder`. In my controller class, say `UsersController`, how can I access to these two classes?

I used to use the `new` way:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->errorResponder = new ErrorResponder();
    $this->successResponder = new SuccessResponder();
}
```

but after I've go through some screencasts (laracast), it looks like the *modern* way is using dependency injection:

```
public function __construct(
    ErrorResponder $errorResponder,
    SuccessResponder $successResponder
) {
    $this->errorResponder   = $errorResponder;
    $this->successResponder = $successResponder;
}
```

So I've been following these for a while, until I used Lumen. I start to think carefully every code that I write. And it really bugged me a lot with no autocomplete in PhpStorm due to dependencies resolved in runtime.

Why dependency injection? Why not just `new`?
Is there merely a *coding style*?

I've look through some of the questions about dependency injection from several years ago but those are like debate topic.

I think it must be useful in certain situation, just that I'm too new to encounter these. So what are those situation that demand dependency injection? Could anyone give me some inspiration?

Comment: Easier testing for one

Answer (score 0):

dependency injection is all about doing things separate and distribute responsibility in things. 
in your case if you used new then all functions in your controller have to create individual objects. 
but if you used contructs then you dont need to create separate objects in functions